# how to pass longitude and latitude from CLLocationManager to use globally swift

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, latitude-longitude

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
        println("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")


    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)


        } else {
            println("Error with the data.")
        }


    })

}
```

Currently I'm able to get the current location with coordinate and I'm able to print it. But how can I send the value in the function to web service? I found that the variable is not accessible outside of the function. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a method out side the function(having parameters for location details) from where you can call web service. Like you are using self.displayLocationInfo(pm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your location variable outside the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method you should declare it right where your class definition starts:

```
class MyClass {
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
}
```

Then in your location delegate method you assign the current value:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    currentCoordinate = manager.location.coordinate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, One question is that the value of latitude and longitude is as latitude=Optional(5.35598300100131)&longitude=Optional(100.288765184531) , i'm calling as below  var longitude = currentCoordinate?.longitude
         var latitude = currentCoordinate?.latitude , is it i did something wrong ?

Comment: Thanks! i solved the problem . i think i did a mistake. Now i'm getting the value by this way         var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = currentCoordinate!
        var longitude = locValue.latitude
        var latitude = locValue.longitude  Really THANKS A LOT.!